# My code has to pass unit tests to print out a Binary Search Tree. but it is templated<T>. The unit tests pass both strings and doubles/longs

Tags: c++, string, templates, casting

My BST must be able to print out numbers and strings from its Node-> data.

```
  virtual string to_string() const { // printing out extra title
     string answer;
     answer.append("# Tree rooted at ");
     answer.append(std::to_string(_root->_data));
     answer.append("\n");
     answer.append(_to_string(_root, answer));
     answer.append("# End of Tree");
     return answer;
  }
```

What is the recommended path so that my to_string method can both append the data if its an integer/double/long and be casted into my string, and if its already a string, otherwise i get an error if the T type is a string.

Comment: `stringstream`.

Comment: Although one can certainly use `stringstream`, it seems obvious to me that the intent of this programming assignment is to learn how to use either specialization, SFINAE, or `if constexpr` to do this. In which case, giving up and using `stringstream` will likely result in a failed grade. So, the "recommended path" is to do whatever the learning material you just covered, before getting this assignment, told you to do.